# what's in the VS express editions for 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-web-developer-2010

If I don't have any version of .NET installed on a Vista OS machine (per the Add/Remove Programs List), will I get the necessary .NET components I need automatically installed for me if I download and install VS2010 Visual Web Developer?  How about if I download Visual C# Express 2010?

In other words, I realize that creating applications with VS2010 requires .NET components, but if I have none of those components will the VS2010 cover that necessity for me when it realizes those components are not present on the OS?

Comment: The install will install the components necessary to _run_ VS2010, as for example .NET Framework 4.0. I'm unsure if it will install all optional .NET versions though, as for example 3.5.1 is not required but selectable as a target.

Comment: You can easily try that! Please never ask a question before trying something or searching the internet. Also this is not the place to ask such a questions.

Comment: MD - would you care to tell me what kind of questions are supposed to be asked here?  I'm assuming you're looking for more challenging questions than something as trivial as this?  Believe me, things like this are not as trivial as it may seem if that's what you're getting at here.